# PHP oci_fetch_all from an Oracle DB converts date value

Tags: php, oracle

I'm having issues getting a value from an Oracle DB where the value is converted to a date format I don't want. I'd prefer to have the raw value, or at least know where I can change that converted date format. Curious if anyone could point me in the right direction here.

```php
$conn = oci_connect(ORACLE_DB_USERNAME, ORACLE_DB_PASSWORD, '//' . ORACLE_DB_HOST . '/' . ORACLE_DB_SID);
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM \"ASSET\".\"NAV\" WHERE sem = '2820' AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY date_time DESC";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql_query);
$row_count = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW + OCI_ASSOC);
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

The data in the DB should come back like:
`CREATE_DATE => '23-07-2019 19:30:11'`

Except, I get this:
`CREATE_DATE => '23-JUL-19'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting dates back in the default format of your database. One thing that you could to is alter the NLS setting of your session to the format that you expect. For this, you can run this command:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
```

Once this command is executed, all dates will be fetched in this format during the lifetime of your Oracle session.

If you are dealing with `timestamp` datatype instead of `date`, then the nls parameter is `nls_timestamp_format` (and `nls_timestamp_tz_format` for `timestamp with timezone`).

---

Another option is to use `to_char()` to format the date to the desired format in the query itself:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT <column list>, to_char(create_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_date FROM ...";
```

Comment: Welcome @joelataylor! Glad that it helped.

Comment: The ALTER has the cost of another statement execution.  Instead you can set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT environment variable.  Check the globalization section of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html